# How to choose the meta learner for the super learner model?

Tags: ensemble-learning

I am building a super learner ensemble model using the classifiers SVM, kNN, AdaBoost, XGBoost, and Random Forest. However I am not sure the logic behind what classifier to use for the meta learner I have seen many applications using logistic regression but I am not using this algorithm since I am doing a classification problem. Is there any logic behind choosing the meta learner?